# Silverlight and XtraReports - opening generated PDF report in new tab in browser

Tags: silverlight, wcf, pdf, devexpress

I'm trying to send a PDF file from a WCF to silverlight client. PDF is generated by DevExpress XtraReports (in method *XtraReport CreateReport(string reportTypeName, RootGenericReportParameterContainer reportInformation)*).

Acually PDF is saved somewhere on clients computer after choosing save path in file save dialog - DevExpress takes care of everything - but I don't have a clue how to open the PDF in new tab in browser.

And here is another problem. Silverlight 4 has no access to local file system right? So information about local PDF location is useless. Maybe it would be better to save the PDF in WCF and send a link to it to the client - but how?

Answer (score 0):

I would first question why you need to send the file to the Silverlight client.  Get rid of that requirement and the solution becomes much simpler.  Silverlight can provide a link that opens a new browser tab.  That link would be handled by the web domain, processing it as an HttpHandler, generating the PDF file for the browser.  Your PDF url doesn't have to reference a physical file, you can still generate it on request, handle querystring values, etc...   Lots of different ways to do this.

Comment: OK so lets say I don't have a requirement for PDF file as a physical file. Hyperlink will be enough. So how can I play with HttpHandler in XraReports WCF methods in order to force client's browser to open new tab with report?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the question isn't really about DevExpress or Silverlight - you're just looking to open a [document of some kind] in a new tab. Each browser natively handles things differently, and users can change tab handling to whatever they want. And (as you mentioned) once the user has downloaded the file, you no longer control it.

Your best bet (and the way I do it) is probably to have a link pointing to a handler/file using "target='_blank' " in the anchor tag on the webpage. From the server side, you would want to set the "Content-Disposition" header to "Inline" to indicate to the browser that the document should be displayed in place instead of downloaded ("Attachment").